# Children and Pesach Sheni

Tags: passover

Is there any Pesach tradition like afikoman, bracha, cleaning the house of chometz, asking questions, etc. that would be prohibited to do on Pesach Sheni?  So if one of your family spent Pesach in hospital, is there any reason that you cannot have a full seder on Pesach Sheni as if it were Pesach?

Comment: Probably actually saying *al achilat matza* etc wouldn't be allowed.

Comment: Pesach sheni is for the korban pesach. Even in the hospital, one would still have to eat matza and drink the four cups (if not pikuach nefesh).

Comment: In Mishna Yossef Hacohen come with all family for Pessach Sheni and chachomim say them to go back. I don't remember where.
יוֹסֵף הַכֹּהֵן הֵבִיא בִכּוּרֵי יַיִן וְשֶׁמֶן, וְלֹא קִבְּלוּ מִמֶּנּוּ. אַף הוּא הֶעֱלָה אֶת בָּנָיו וּבְנֵי בֵיתוֹ לַעֲשׂוֹת פֶּסַח קָטָן בִּירוּשָׁלַיִם, וְהֶחֱזִירוּהוּ, שֶׁלֹּא יִקָּבַע הַדָּבָר חוֹבָה
You see that to make non-necessary things on Pessach sheni may be a problem

Comment: @kouty It's the last Mishna in Challah